# Is 'NoneType' object is not iterable due to SQL column types?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am running the below simple code, which is taking an SQL query and writing to csv file. I am receiving the 'NoneType' object is not iterable error, which I see other posts about, but have not answered my question. My question is, could these be due to my SQL column types? If so, how can I find out my SQL column types and change the type?

```
print("Importing modules...")

import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import os
import pantab
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

print("Done importing modules.")

server = 'server'
db = 'db'
conn_sql = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')


sql_query =  open('sql.sql', 'r').read()

df_sql_output = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, conn_sql)

now = dt.datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
now = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df_sql_output.to_csv(r'path ' +now + '.csv')
```

Comment: It's most likely that you didn't get any results

Comment: @roganjosh I dont think thats the case. When I run the query in SQL, I get ~30,000 results. I am inserting and using various temp tables, could that be an issue?

Comment: I haven't used that method before, but don't you have to pass a query string to `read_sql_query`, not the contents of a file?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to run a proper SQL query and convert the result to a dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

server = 'server'
db = 'db'
conn_sql = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')

sql_query = "SELECT your_data FROM your_table"

df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn_sql)
```

Comment: I actually tried that as well, but received the same traceback error:   
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1440, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Did you try to fetch a result to see if your query works without involving pandas?